# Regular expressions as a list on python

Tags: python

I'm facing an error when I try to print my objects retrieved with re.search method.
Here is the output:

> $ ./io.py
>
> None

Althought I have sucessfully stored my regular expressions on an object list, looks like there is some error when passing the arguments to the re.match() method.

Can someone give me a hint ?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import io
import re

# my regular expressions
exprs = [ """r"Gene ID: (.*)\,""", """r"(.*)\[Homo sapiens]""", 
          """r"from:(.*)\s""",  """r"NM_(.*)\.([0-9]+)""" ,     
          """r"NP_(.*)\.([0-9]+)\s""", """r"\,(.*)[^coding]exons""",  
          """r"AA length:(.*)\s""", """r"isoform(.*)\\NP""" ]


# search for expressions vector in genetable
for element in exprs:
    arq = open('massaCHD8.txt', "r")
    resu = re.search(element, arq.read(), re.M|re.I)
    print(resu)
    arq.close()
```

Comment: "I'm facing an error" - what is the error?

Comment: If you see an error, include the error stack trace in your question. If you do not see an error, explain what kind of error you suspect to have, and what is the expected output.

Comment: whoops sorry.. .editing

Comment: Why do define `exprs_size`, only to hard-code the upper bound in your loop? Besides that, if you want to iterate over a container, you don't need the index at all: `for element in container: doSomeProcessing(element)`

Comment: Once you have read the file once, you can't read it again without seeking back to the start, so only the first call to `arq.read()` will return anything. Why are you triple quoting your regexes? the `r"` prefix to a string marks it as a raw string, but you quoting that means your regex is looking for `r"Gene ID` inside your text, which seems unlikely to be what you intend.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler In addition to your point, I'd also like to point out that Python has an idiom for safely reading a file: `with open(fn, mode) as f: processFileSomehow(f)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to use raw strings, but you enclose them in quotes.

Instead of

```
"""r"Gene ID: (.*)\,"""
```

try:

```
r"Gene ID: (.*)\,"
```

In regular expressions, the `*` is greedy, so it will match *everything* until the last `,`. Is that what you intended?

Note that `\,` means `,` because the comma isn't a special character. If you want to match a backslash followed by a comma, use `\\,` *even in a raw string regex*.

Furthermore, you re-read the whole file for every regular expression. You should read the file contents *before* the loop.

```
with open('massaCHD8.txt', "r") as df:
    arq = df.read()
for element in exprs:
    results = re.search(element, arq)
```

Note that search only finds the *first match*! If you want to find all matches, use `re.findall` instead.

Comment: @G.BossNoobware I'm glad it did. For the next time you ask a question, it would be helpful if you could include a small sample of the input and the expected output. That makes it easier for us to answer your question accurately.